# Ruby on Rails DataTable not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatable

[DataTable Ruby on Rails guide](https://github.com/phronos/rails_datatables/blob/master/README.md)

I"m following the above and have installed the git plugin as well by running

```
rails plugin install https://github.com/phronos/rails_datatables.git
```

I"m just trying to get some nice looking tables on my Rails page. If there is an easier way to achieve this without using the plugin, please let me know.

All i'm getting is the  <%= datatable() %> outputting this text on my page

```
`<script type="text/javascript"> $(function() { $('#expenses').dataTable({ "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "Search", "sProcessing": 'Processing' }, "sPaginationType": "full_numbers", "iDisplayLength": 25, "bProcessing": true, "bServerSide": false, "bLengthChange": false, "bStateSave": true, "bFilter": true, "bAutoWidth": true, 'aaSorting': [[0, 'desc']], "aoColumns": [ { 'sType': 'html', 'bSortable':true, 'bSearchable':true ,'sClass':'first' },{ 'sType': 'html', 'bSortable':true, 'bSearchable':true },{ 'sType': 'html', 'bSortable':true, 'bSearchable':true },{ 'sType': 'string', 'bSortable':true, 'bSearchable':true ,'sClass':'last' } ], "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) { aoData.push( ); $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { fnCallback(json); } ); } }); }); </script>"`.
```

My .html.erb looks like this:

```
<% @page_title="User Page"%> 

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <%=javascript_include_tag "jquery.dataTables" %>
     <%=stylesheet_link_tag "jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom" %>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>

<% if current_user %>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Expenses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Accountant</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Requests (<%=@requests.count%>)</a></li>    
    </ul>
     <div id="tabs-3">
       <p>
        <% if @requests.count != 0 %>
        <h2> Accountant Requests </h2>

        <table >
          <tr>
              <thead>

            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Accept</th>
            <th>Reject</th>
                </thead>
          </tr>

          <% @requests.each do |request| %>
            <tr>
            <td><%= request.accountant.first_name %></td>
            <td><%= request.accountant.last_name %></td>
            <td><%= request.accountant.email %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'accept', confirm_accountant_path(:accountant_id => request.accountant_id) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_expense_path(request) %></td>      
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <% else %>
            <h4> You have no pending requests <h4>
        <% end %>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
       <p>
        <% if @accountants.count != 0 %>
        <h2> Accountant Info </h2>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
          </tr>
          <% @accountants.each do |accountant| %>
            <tr>
            <td><%= accountant.first_name %></td>
            <td><%= accountant.last_name %></td>
            <td><%= accountant.email %></td>        
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </table>
        <% else %>
            <h4> Add Accountant  <h4>
            <p> You don't have an accountant yet, perhaps consider adding one by e-mail </p>
            <%= render 'add_accountant_form' %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p><% if current_user %>
    <h4> Submit new expense </h4>
    <%= render 'expenses/form' %>
     <% columns = [{:type => 'html', :class => "first"}, {:type => 'html'}, 
    {:type => 'html'}, {:type => nil, :class => "last"}] %>
<%= datatable(columns, {:sort_by => "[0, 'desc']", table_dom_id:"expenses" }) %>
    <table id="expenses" class="datatable">
        <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Entry Date</th>
        <th>Last Update</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Receipt</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
        </thead>
        <% @expenses.each do |user_expense| %>

<tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user_expense.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= user_expense.updated_at %></td>
        <td><%= user_expense.amount %></td>
        <td><%= user_expense.user.username %></td>
            <% if !user_expense.receipt_img.nil? %>
                <td><%= image_tag user_expense.receipt_img.url(:thumb) %></td>
            <% else %>
                <td>Future Button Here</td>
            <% end %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_expense %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_expense_path(user_expense) %></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
        <% end %>
    </table>
<% end %></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier alternative: [Rails: Spice Up Your Tables with DataTables](http://www.jacoulter.com/2012/01/03/rails-spice-up-your-tables-with-datatables/)

It worked well, I"m going to uninstall the plugin which didn't work out.

Here is my updated html.erb:

```
<% @page_title="User Page"%> 

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <%=javascript_include_tag "jquery.dataTables"%>
     <%=stylesheet_link_tag "jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom"%>
      <%=stylesheet_link_tag "demo_table"%>



    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#expenses').dataTable();
  } );
    </script>



<% if current_user %>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Expenses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Accountant</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Requests (<%=@requests.count%>)</a></li>    
    </ul>
     <div id="tabs-3">
       <p>
        <% if @requests.count != 0 %>
        <h2> Accountant Requests </h2>

        <table >
          <tr>
              <thead>

            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Accept</th>
            <th>Reject</th>
                </thead>
          </tr>

          <% @requests.each do |request| %>
            <tr>
            <td><%= request.accountant.first_name %></td>
            <td><%= request.accountant.last_name %></td>
            <td><%= request.accountant.email %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'accept', confirm_accountant_path(:accountant_id => request.accountant_id) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_expense_path(request) %></td>      
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <% else %>
            <h4> You have no pending requests <h4>
        <% end %>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
       <p>
        <% if @accountants.count != 0 %>
        <h2> Accountant Info </h2>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
          </tr>
          <% @accountants.each do |accountant| %>
            <tr>
            <td><%= accountant.first_name %></td>
            <td><%= accountant.last_name %></td>
            <td><%= accountant.email %></td>        
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </table>
        <% else %>
            <h4> Add Accountant  <h4>
            <p> You don't have an accountant yet, perhaps consider adding one by e-mail </p>
            <%= render 'add_accountant_form' %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p><% if current_user %>
    <h4> Submit new expense </h4>
    <%= render 'expenses/form' %>
    <table id="expenses" class="display">
        <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Entry Date</th>
        <th>Last Update</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Receipt</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
        </thead>

            <tbody>
        <% @expenses.each do |user_expense| %>


      <tr>
        <td><%= user_expense.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= user_expense.updated_at %></td>
        <td><%= user_expense.amount %></td>
        <td><%= user_expense.user.username %></td>
            <% if !user_expense.receipt_img.nil? %>
                <td><%= image_tag user_expense.receipt_img.url(:thumb) %></td>
            <% else %>
                <td>Future Button Here</td>
            <% end %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_expense %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_expense_path(user_expense) %></td>
      </tr>

        <% end %>
    </tbody>
    </table>
<% end %></p>
    </div>

</div>
```